# MSSQL: Update row returns duplicate key error

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I'm building a web app using CodeIgniter and MSSQL, but when I try to update a row in the DB I'm getting a "duplicate key" error:

```
Error Number: 23000
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.users' with unique index 'IX_users'. 
The duplicate key value is (user@mail.com).

UPDATE users SET email='user@mail.com', name='User', surname='Surname', password='1234'
```

This happens when I run the update whether the e-mail field stays the same or not. I'm no expert on MSSQL, but I don't see the issue in updating a row and keeping the *unique* fields the same.

I'm happy to provide any additional info you might need.

Comment: what are the column present in `IX_users` Index. If only `email` column then `'user@mail.com'` value is already present in `email column`

Comment: I hope only `email` column present in `IX_users` Index. since`'user@mail.com'` value is already present in `email column` you got this error. Unique index will not allow duplicate values

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that, though I have no idea what the IX_users index is or how it works.

Comment: i think you forgot the `where` cluase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is simple, you are updating all users to get the same email

```
UPDATE users 
SET email='user@mail.com', name='User', surname='Surname', password='1234'
```

Missing WHERE clause. Example:

```
WHERE email='user@mail.com'
```

Comment: Thanks, it _was_ that. I thought CodeIgniter was handling this but I must have gotten it wrong. It works now, so thanks, again.